# How to get correct data from QSortFilterProxyModel PyQt

Tags: pyqt, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a `QTreeView` with `QSortFilterProxyModel`. When I click on any item of the view, this prints the index from the clicked row. Before and after setting the filter it prints the same index.

I need this for `removeRow()`, but when I put index, it removes the incorrect item from the list :/

How to delete the correct selected row?

Example:

Not Sorted

```
 ITEM 1
 ITEM 2 -> Click: Print ITEM2 and this is removed
 ITEM 3
 ITEM 4
```

Sorted

```
ITEM 2
ITEM 4 -> Click: Print ITEM2 and ITEM2 is removed :/
```

---

```
init
    self.menuIndex = None

    self.mModelMenu = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 4, self)
    self.mModelMenu.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Id")
    self.mModelMenu.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Descripcion")
    self.mModelMenu.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Categoria")
    self.mModelMenu.setHeaderData(3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Cantidad")

    self.mProxyModelMenu = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
    self.mProxyModelMenu.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
    self.mProxyModelMenu.setSourceModel(self.mModelMenu)

    self.mTreeView = QtGui.QTreeView()
    self.mTreeView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
    self.mTreeView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    self.mTreeView.setModel(self.mProxyModelMenu)
    self.mTreeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.mTreeView.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
    self.mTreeView.resizeColumnToContents(0)
    self.mTreeView.clicked.connect(self.getIndex)

    mPushButton1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Borrar")
    mPushButton1.clicked.connect(self.newInMenu)

def getIndex()
    print(index.row())
    self.menuIndex = index.data(index.row())
    print(index.data(index.row()))
    # print(index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole))

def removeFromMenu(self):
    toRemove = self.menuIndex
    self.mModelMenu.removeRow(0) #this delete the last row, but i need delete current selected row
```

Comment: We need to see the code.

Comment: now I put the code :)

Comment: Why do you use `removeRow(0)` if you want to delete the selected one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to work with the proxy model is to avoid working on the original model and use `QSortFilterProxyModel` methods when possible.

E.g. simply invoking `removeRow` on the proxy model:

```
def removeFromMenu(self)
    selIndexes = self.mTreeView.selectedIndexes()
    if len(selIndexes):
        first = selIndexes[0]
        self.mProxyModelMenu.removeRow(first.row(), first.parent())
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It works in part. After mixing the content eliminates the wrong row.  I had to make a change, but eliminates the index in negative order

Comment: I added the `parent` argument, that should be providided for TreeModels.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfect, now I just need to get the contents of the ID column;). I understand that I work with ProxyModel, I'm still new to Qt. thanks for the help :)

Comment: By the same logic I got the data from index, this is perfect: D!

Answer (score 2):

When using a `QSortFilterProxyModel`, you have two types of index: the proxy indexes (the order you see on the view) and the source indexes from the original model (the order in the `QStandardItemModel`).

The view will give you the proxy index, and you can go back to the source index with [mapToSource](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#mapToSource), like this:

```
#get first selected index
proxy_index = self.mTreeView.selectedIndexes()[0] 

#convert 
source_index=self.mProxyModelMenu.mapToSource(proxy_index)

#delete row in source model
self.mModelMenu.removeRow(source_index.row())
```

Comment: This implementation throws an error, 
QSortFilterProxyModel: index passed from wrong model to mapFromSource